# Backup Scenarios

Tags: sql-server

In My Computer, on C drive I have a Database of 50GB and I want to take backup of that 50 GB data to other drives D,E,F but D,E,F Drives contain only 20 GB for each. In this scenario how can i take Backup to other drives of C drive data.

Comment: Programming related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compress the database and split the archiv to 20 GB each (for example with 7zip on commandline).

Comment: I didn't understand ..Can you elaborate

Comment: You take for example winzip add the 50GB File to a archiv und split the archiv into 3 parts (two times 20GB one time 10GB) and copy the parts to your drives D,E,F

Answer (score 11):

You can split the backup into multiple files

Check http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=935

Comment: +1 for being a SQL solution to the question. Plus you get better performance when splitting the backup to multiple devices.

Comment: This should have been as the chosen answer :-).

Comment: What matter's is to help others, and exchange idea's isn't it?! Thank you all for the upvoting

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a backup if there is no space for it. You simply need more space.

You could compress backup after you made it, but you need space to make it. Not sure how much free space you have on C drive. If you have enough, you can backup it to C drive and then compress with whatever zip, rar, 7z whatever you have.

If you had SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, or SQL Server 2008 R2, you could use [Backup Compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719.aspx) feature.

Something to consider:

- there are might be data, that you don't need, so you could delete some
- try to shrink the datafile

Don't know what OS you have but, you could also create one [Spanned Volume](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772180.aspx) from D,E,F.

Answer (score -1):

in a very simple way

> increse the disk size of D,E,F
>
> Write a house keeping job , to put the data on the tape.

Comment: I need without increasing size of D,E,F.